# Database table design with money and periods

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose I have database table like Employee and each employee has associated wage. Wages can be different in different periods of time. How can I design a table storing these wages? ("wage periods" cannot overlap, but this constraint does not have to be handled by the database)

Employee will not be the only table needing such a date-modal currency data.

I was thinking about a table with two primary keys (a "wageId" integer and a datetime) and a wage column (integer, counting pennies as suggested). Employee (or any other) table would have a column "wage" referencing the "wageId". Datetime would be the date up to which the wage is valid. Does that make any sense? Could it be improved?

I'm using mysql.

Comment: don't store money values in a floating-point field. You WILL get wonky results at some point. Either use a fixed-point format (e.g. store as pennies), or a "decimal" type.

Comment: thank you, I will go for the "pennies" approach

Comment: Do you ever anticipate doing some calculation such as 'avg' on the money values where you could get fractions of a penny? I would suggest adding a couple of more digits to make it units of hundredths of a penny. Stock exchanges do this. For example 560 pennies is $5.60, but use 56000 instead.

Comment: I will do calculations on the wages, but not on the database side. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of a slowly changing dimension.  A good reference on database design are books by Ralph Kimball.

In any case, what you want is a table called something like `EmployeeWage`.  This would have columns such as:

- EmployeeWageId, a unique id for the row
- EmployeeId, identifier for the employee
- Wage, the wage
- EffDate, date the wage took effect
- EndDate, date the wage stopped being effective.

I would also add columns such as who created each row and the exact time, but that is outside the scope of your question.

Comment: assuming employees cannot have two wages at the same time, you'd only ever really need the date a wage started. it would implicitly end when another wage "takes over".

Comment: @MarcB . . . Having the end date simplifies many queries.  With a simple query, you can find the wage at any time.  You can find the current wage.  The end date may seem redundant but it is really part of the "key" for each record makes the table much easier to use.

Comment: I guess it's fine, but I was thinking of a more universal approach allowing me to use the XyzWage table each time I need it anywhere else. Is that a bad thing to aim for? Should I make new Wage tables each time I need it? Alternatively I could add more Ids like "employeeId" but it seems weird...

Comment: @user1713059 . . . I don't understand your comment at all.  You would have one `EmployeeWage` table for all employees and all wages.  You need to query it with an employee id and a date.  You wouldn't be creating and dropping such a table, just inserting new rows in and updating existing rows.

Comment: "Employee will not be the only table needing such a date-modal currency data." There will be other objects (tables) needing a way to store currencies changing in time. Sorry, my powers of explanation are weak I guess.

Comment: What would happen if you had an employee that had two jobs at the same company; for example in the morning s/he works at the help desk for $20/hour and in the afternoon s/he works doing data entry for $25/hour?

Comment: I guess employee should have a defined position (separate table), and wage should be part of the table combining employee and position (the table defining the many-to-many relation of employee and position).

Comment: @Marichyasana . . . I keep thinking about your point, and it seems to emphasize the need for data modeling, which is about clarifying exactly what entities are.  As the OP says, this should perhaps really be by position or position/employee.

Comment: I accepted the answer, but I don't like the fact that I have to create separate wage/price tables for each object like employee (wage changes), ticket (price changes), card (price changes in time, but bases on card type), etc.